# Problems styling and animating fl_chart bar chart

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to use a bar chart that needs to show both positive and negative values, but I am facing three issues:

1. I am unable to fit the chart into the card I am displaying it in.
2. I want the chart to animate when the tab is loaded, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Here is an image of what's happening:
[Screenshot of the page displaying the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpG9y.png)

Here is the code for the Bar chart section:

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/Charts/bar_data.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BarGraph extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? maxY;
  final double monAmount;
  final double tueAmount;
  final double wedAmount;
  final double thuAmount;
  final double friAmount;
  final double satAmount;
  final double sunAmount;

  const BarGraph({
    super.key,
    required this.maxY,
    required this.monAmount,
    required this.tueAmount,
    required this.wedAmount,
    required this.thuAmount,
    required this.friAmount,
    required this.satAmount,
    required this.sunAmount,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //initialize bar data
    BarData myData = BarData(
      monAmount: monAmount,
      tueAmount: tueAmount,
      wedAmount: wedAmount,
      thuAmount: thuAmount,
      friAmount: friAmount,
      satAmount: satAmount,
      sunAmount: sunAmount,
    );
    myData.initializeBarData();
        

    return BarChart(
      BarChartData(
        maxY: maxY,
        minY: 0,
        gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
        borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            show: true,
            topTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            leftTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            rightTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                showTitles: true,
                getTitlesWidget: getBottomTitles,
              ),
            )),
        barGroups: myData.barData
            .map(
              (data) => BarChartGroupData(
                x: data.x,
                barRods: [
                  BarChartRodData(
                    toY: data.y,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    width: 25,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    backDrawRodData: BackgroundBarChartRodData(
                      show: true,
                      fromY: double.parse('-$maxY'),
                      toY: maxY,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
      swapAnimationCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
      swapAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      
    );
  }
}

Widget getBottomTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14);

  Widget text;

  switch (value.toInt()) {
    case 0:
      text = Text(
        'Mon',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 1:
      text = Text(
        'Tue',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 2:
      text = Text(
        'Wed',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 3:
      text = Text(
        'Thu',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 4:
      text = Text(
        'Fri',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 5:
      text = Text(
        'Sat',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 6:
      text = Text(
        'Sun',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    default:
      text = Text(
        '',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
  }
  return SideTitleWidget(
    axisSide: meta.axisSide,
    child: text,
  );
}
```

1. I have tried padding, sizedbox, container etc. but nothing works on the barchart.
2. For the animation, I am simply not aware of what I can do to make it happen.

Here is a reproducible version of the code. `IndividualBar`, `BarData` and `BarGraph` are all in different dart files in the original code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
              child: const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                child: BarGraph(
                  maxY: 50,
                  monAmount: 20,
                  tueAmount: 25,
                  wedAmount: 43,
                  thuAmount: -10,
                  friAmount: -36,
                  satAmount: 16,
                  sunAmount: -10,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IndividualBar {
  final int x; //position on x axis
  final double y; //amount

  IndividualBar({required this.x, required this.y});
}

class BarData {
  final double monAmount;
  final double tueAmount;
  final double wedAmount;
  final double thuAmount;
  final double friAmount;
  final double satAmount;
  final double sunAmount;

  BarData({
    required this.monAmount,
    required this.tueAmount,
    required this.wedAmount,
    required this.thuAmount,
    required this.friAmount,
    required this.satAmount,
    required this.sunAmount,
  });

  //make a list from Individual bar data
  List<IndividualBar> barData = [];

  //initialize bar data
  void initializeBarData() {
    barData = [
      //mon
      IndividualBar(x: 0, y: monAmount),
      //tue
      IndividualBar(x: 1, y: tueAmount),
      //wed
      IndividualBar(x: 2, y: wedAmount),
      //thu
      IndividualBar(x: 3, y: thuAmount),
      //fri
      IndividualBar(x: 4, y: friAmount),
      //sat
      IndividualBar(x: 5, y: satAmount),
      //sun
      IndividualBar(x: 6, y: sunAmount),
    ];
  }
}

class BarGraph extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? maxY;
  final double monAmount;
  final double tueAmount;
  final double wedAmount;
  final double thuAmount;
  final double friAmount;
  final double satAmount;
  final double sunAmount;

  const BarGraph({
    super.key,
    required this.maxY,
    required this.monAmount,
    required this.tueAmount,
    required this.wedAmount,
    required this.thuAmount,
    required this.friAmount,
    required this.satAmount,
    required this.sunAmount,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //initialize bar data
    BarData myData = BarData(
      monAmount: monAmount,
      tueAmount: tueAmount,
      wedAmount: wedAmount,
      thuAmount: thuAmount,
      friAmount: friAmount,
      satAmount: satAmount,
      sunAmount: sunAmount,
    );
    myData.initializeBarData();

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: BarChart(
        BarChartData(
          //alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceAround,
          maxY: maxY,
          minY: double.parse('-$maxY'),
          gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
          borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
              show: true,
              topTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
              ),
              leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
              ),
              rightTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
              ),
              bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  getTitlesWidget: getBottomTitles,
                ),
              )),
          barGroups: myData.barData
              .map(
                (data) => BarChartGroupData(
                  x: data.x,
                  barRods: [
                    BarChartRodData(
                      toY: data.y,
                      color: data.y > 0
                          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 212, 138)
                          : const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 0, 0),
                      width: 40,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 2.0,
                        color: data.y > 0
                            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 169, 119)
                            : const Color.fromARGB(255, 171, 23, 23),
                      ),
                      backDrawRodData: BackgroundBarChartRodData(
                        show: true,
                        fromY: double.parse('-$maxY'),
                        toY: maxY,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
        swapAnimationCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
        swapAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget getBottomTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14);

  Widget text;

  switch (value.toInt()) {
    case 0:
      text = Text(
        'Mon',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 1:
      text = Text(
        'Tue',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 2:
      text = Text(
        'Wed',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 3:
      text = Text(
        'Thu',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 4:
      text = Text(
        'Fri',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 5:
      text = Text(
        'Sat',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    case 6:
      text = Text(
        'Sun',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
    default:
      text = Text(
        '',
        style: style,
      );
      break;
  }
  return SideTitleWidget(
    axisSide: meta.axisSide,
    child: text,
  );
}
```

It's probably very clear from all this that I am very new to Flutter... so I will rely on the help of the amazing people here! :)

Thanks in advance!